# Change Font Size Based on Language

Tags: html, css, unicode

So i have read a few suggestions with the css language tag, but it seems like everything requires placing the language in the tag in advanced.  I am not able to change the html tags around the korean language, it has the same h1 tag as the english.  It is because it is a translated version of the same website.

I want to have a different font and font size for the korean version than the english.  Can i do this by just knowing the language?  I found some other questions dealing with the unicode range  that used @font-face {  }  , for one, I cant figure out what unicode range Korean is, i have tried looking at all the documentation but i just dont comprehend how unicode ranges are calculated and written.  Also, i was hoping there was an option like,

```
h1{
unicode-range: korean;
font-size: 10px;
}

h1{
unicode-range: english;
font-size 20px;
}
```

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigining different font-size per each font in one font-family](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153403/assigining-different-font-size-per-each-font-in-one-font-family)

Comment: There are various questions that deal with the same basic topic, see also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535616/can-css-choose-a-different-default-font-and-size-depending-on-language

Comment: my question is different, considering the answer to that was find one font that works on all languages... korean and english are very different styles and design wise requires specific fonts

Comment: the second link is actually what i had seen and am referencing in my comment,  i wanted to know if there was a way to do it based on a heading tag as opposed to a font-face and using the font family

Comment: There is a way to do it, as pointed in my answer. The way your website switches languages, it assignes an attribute to the `html` tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your case the `lang` attribute is set on the `html` tag, so you could style all the elements you need based on that using the rules:

```
html:lang(en) h1{
    font-size: 20px;
}

html:lang(ko) h1{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Be careful, though, the the `:lang` pseudo-class is supported only in IE8+. Should you need support in IE7+, your best bet is going for the syntax of this type: `a[lang="en"]`.

Comment: so your saying that because the language is korean the html is automatically given a html:lang(ko) tag?

Comment: That is how your website handles language switching. I tried myself using *developer tools* to add those rules and they work. You can see inspecting your website that the `<html>` tag (i.e. the main wrapper of your code) is being added the attribute `lang=en-US` or `lang=ko-KR`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the CSS [`:lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3alang) pseudo class if you set the `lang` attribute in your HTML to alter the style. For example [**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dGnP8/) or the following code:

**CSS**

```
:lang(en) {
    font-size:20px;
}

:lang(fr) {
    font-size:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p lang="en">Lorem</p>
<p lang="fr">Lorem</p>
```

Comment: the website is written in english, it then has a translated version which is exactly the same, except the words are translated to korean.  if i wrap the original in a lang attribute, the korean translation will have the same lang attribute, so i wont be able to reference it

Comment: The question states that modifying the HTML markup is not possible.

Comment: it is using wpml from wordpress, www.sarahleejs.com  is the actual website if it helps make sense of what i am talking about

Comment: Yes it helps, since you can see that the `lang` attribute on the `<html>` element is altered. So we can use this approach.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly but `lang` changes on the `<html>` element are automatic with the site in question so this approach will still work.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful: http://billposer.org/Linguistics/Computation/UnicodeRanges.html

You're looking for **Hangul** which is "The Korean alphabet, also known as Hangul,[nb 1] or Chosongul"

Regards

Comment: The question is after a way of differentiating. Setting the `unicode-range` will not allow you to style that particular range differently.

Comment: Could you provide working css to make the answer truly complete?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using some dynamic language as server side of your website, you can simply do a dynamic CSS loading based on the Locale.

E.g. you have, in css folder, the following:

```
style.css        // this is the default
style_en_US.css
style_ko_KR.css
```

So you can have a separation of global settings from locale-specific ones and can load the required style dynamically with ease.

If you have a static HTML page instead, you can have JavaScript to load the CSS dynamically or you can use the

```
:lang
```

pseudo-class as pointed by others as well.

Whatever solution you choose, remember to keep an eye on browser-compatibility.

*NOTE: Often it is a better solution to have the user explicitly select his/her preferred locale instead of automatically setting one based on the client's system information.*

Answer (score 0):

Change the style sheet on language select

```
<body onload="set_style_from_cookie()">

//style sheet
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="korean"
    href="http://example.com/css/korean.css">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="english"
    href="http://example.com/css/english.css">

//form to select language using button
<form>
<input type="submit"
  onclick="switch_style('korean');return false;"
  name="theme" value="korean Language" id="korean">
<input type="submit"
  onclick="switch_style('english');return false;"
  name="theme" value="english language" id="english">
</form>

//javascript
<script>
// *** TO BE CUSTOMISED ***

var style_cookie_name = "style" ;
var style_cookie_duration = 30 ;

// *** END OF CUSTOMISABLE SECTION ***

function switch_style ( css_title )
{

  var i, link_tag ;
  for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
    i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
    if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
      link_tag[i].title) {
      link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
      if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
        link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
      }
    }
    set_cookie( style_cookie_name, css_title,
      style_cookie_duration );
  }
}
function set_style_from_cookie()
{
  var css_title = get_cookie( style_cookie_name );
  if (css_title.length) {
    switch_style( css_title );
  }
}
function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
    lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{

    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                       ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
                       "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                       "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                       24 * lifespan_in_days +
                       "; path=/" + domain_string ;
}
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{

    var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
    if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
        var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                        '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                        cookie_name +
                        '=([^;]*)' );
        return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
    }
    return '' ;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use something similar to:

```
h1[lang=en] {
  font-size: 10px;
}

h1[lang=kr] {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

or if you would like to only specify `lang=""` once, instead of on every element, you could do

```
#content[lang=en] h1 {

}

#content[lang=en] p {

}

#content[lang=kr] h1 {

}

#content[lang=kr] p {

}
```

Comment: This only works if the HTML element has the `lang` attribute specified.